# ReactJS component reloading unexpectedly on className change

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, user-interface

TLDR;
Does adding a className to an exciting `div` reload the parent component in **ReactJs**? Added images near button to show `console.log` being called multiple times.

**Here is the bug..**

I'm building a simple 'order' app, which includes a sidebar.

I recreated the sidebar in a new project for a sanity check. Same issues. Here is the simple version.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      addList : [],
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Sidebar list = {this.state.addList}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and in the sidebar component

```
class Sidebar extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            active : false
        }
    }
    toggleSidebar () {
        if (this.state.active) {
            this.setState({
                active : false
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                active: true
            })
        }
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div className={ 'sidebar ' + ((this.state.active) ? '' : 'hidden')}>
                <button className='tab' onClick={(e)=>{this.toggleSidebar()}}>
                        TAB
                </button>
                <div className="itemList">
                    {console.log(this.props.list)}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

The sideBar class has a `position: fixed` and I move it out of the screen on a button click and adding a `hidden` className (`.hidden { right: -x }`)

When an item gets selected in the parent app component, it gets added to its state (`addItem`).

The Sidebar component has that property passed into so when addItem get a new item, it displays it. It works just as predicted. I was able to add items and display them no problem.

I noticed the bug when I started adding number and doing price totals etc, because it seems the sidebar keep rendering I would find myself getting caught in *infinite setState loops*

Any solutions or advice?

Images for a those that are visual (clicking the tab and console displaying):

[image: original load]

[image: after a click]

[image: after many clicks]

Comment: Changing a className shouldn't reload any component, however you do not provide enough code to allow finding the problem. Maybe add the code where you modify the className.

Comment: @Ankari I had added much more code and detail. I hope this is sufficient

Comment: The code you provided so far works well as you said it yourself. The answer you provided is rather a workaround than a solution to your question I would say. If you provide a code that can reproduce the issue, maybe I can give you a better explanation of what happening and provide an actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, I'm foolish. In fact I AM changing the state of sidebar causes a reload.

Therefor to get around this is having the parent component hold the values and pass them down as properties for the sidebar to just display. Therefor on reload the values don't change or re-add.